# Increase Output Resolution of Python cProfile (More Resolution in Output Required)

Tags: python, profiling, resolution, timing, cprofile

I am profiling a simple Python function such as

```
def prof_func():
    x = 100
    y = 100
    a = np.random.rand(x,y)
    c = signal.convolve2d(a, a, boundary='symm', mode='same')
```

using cProfile but the times I get out only have a resolution of three decimal places.
How can I have cProfile print a greater number of decimal places so I can see how long the `a = np.random.rand(x,y)`  line takes. Currently cProfile tells me that it takes 0.000s.

I had hoped that there would be an easy way to increase the resolution of the cProfile output but I have checked the documentation and not found one: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround I used to get more significant figures using `cprofile` and `pstats`. The `pstats.Stats.print_stats()` method uses a function called `f8` (see [1](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/pstats.py)), that returns the numbers with a fixed format. By defining a similar function in your script where the profiling is made, such as:

```py
def f8_alt(x):
    return "%14.9f" % x
```

and monkey patching the static method

```py
pstats.f8 = f8_alt
```

the `print_stats()` method will return the output with more decimals.

Hope it helps!

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/pstats.py